# Having trouble getting packages to recognize

Tags: java, android, android-package-managers

I have two different packages inside of my application. The trouble I am having is the packages wont recognize each other.

```
package sticyface.androidgames.framework.impl;
package sticyface.androidgames.framework;
```

when I try to import a java file from one to the other I receive an error under stickyface. It says "The import sticyface cannot be resolved.
Example

```
import stickyface.androidgames.framework.Input.TouchEvent;
```

What am I forgetting to do?

Comment: `sticyface` and `stickyface` are not the same thing.

Comment: Its called difference of 'k' in package name.

Comment: epic fail how did i miss that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your filesystem, you may have created two different structures on the filesystem (which the package definition mirrors.

stickyface.androidgames.framework.Input.TouchEvent -> {src dir}/stickyface/androidgames/framework/Input/TouchEvent.class

So if TouchEvent.class is not in that directory then it can't be imported in.  You can also try replacing TouchEvent with * in the import line just in case, that'll import in what needs dynamically.